# Laravel layouts not working

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans-8

I am trying something really simple and can not get it to work. 
I have 2 pages. admin.blade.php and left.blade.php
I am trying to use admin page as the master page. and include date from left.blade.php

The admin pages print only "test" as the result and includes nothing from left.admin.php. 
I can`t see what is wrong. Thanks in advance

File structure is

```
-- resources
   --views
     *admin.blade.php
     *left.blade.php
```

left.blade.php

```
@extends('admin')

@section('content')
   baran
@stop
```

admin.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>

    @yield('content')

    test
<div id='footer'>
    @yield('footer')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

route command in web.php is

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include date from `left.blade.php` you should use `@include()` directive in `admin.blade.php`:

```
@include('left')
```

If your main content is in `left.blade.php` and you're using `admin.blade.php` as layout only then change you route:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('left');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call the view for the inner page, not the master page, since the inner page extends the master page:

```
return view('left');
```